# Twilio Programmable Chat — keep app badge in sync with unread message count

Tags: ios, push-notification, twilio

We'd like our app's icon badge number to reflect the total number of unread Twilio messages. In the app we're using delegate methods to get a count of unread messages across all channels, but we're unable to do this when the app is backgrounded. According to the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/push-notification-configuration#push-configuring), we can set `Notifications.NewMessage.BadgeCountEnabled=true`, but that will only give us the number of 1:1 channels containing unread messages.

Is there a way to get a total unread count for the `badge` value in the `aps` dictionary instead?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that it's not possible to include the count of all unread messages right now, that is just how it works currently.

We do expect to extend the ways you can use this in the future, but there's no timeline for that sort of work just yet.

Comment: Do Twilio have any update to avail of this functionality? Any workaround for this?

Comment: The latest is in [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/push-notification-configuration#badge-count). I'd have a read and see if it works for your application and reach out to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) if it doesn't.